# -Replace Operator not accepting capture group variable and user variable at once

Tags: powershell

In the below example if I use single quotes for the `-Replace` operator (`'Tag000: (.*)', 'Tag000: $1 hello $scategory'`) the capture group variable (`$1`) gets resolved at run time, while `$scategory` does not.
If I use double quotes (`-replace "Tag000: (.*)", "Tag000: $1 hello $scategory"`) the `$scategory` variable works but then the capture group varibale is not recognised

```
$scategory = "my car is red "
$Read_Opus_Category= Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\Chapter 6.ps1" -Stream multitags.txt -Raw
$Modified_Opus_Category= $Read_Opus_Category -replace 'Tag000: (.*)', "Tag000: $1 hello $scategory"
```

Am at a loss here, any help would be wonderfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `` ` `` to escape the `$` in an expandable string literal:

```
$Read_Opus_Category -replace 'Tag000: (.*)', "Tag000: `$1 hello $scategory"
```

Comment: D'oh I keep forgetting this pesky escape character! thank you darling